# Simultaneous SELECT and UPDATE - Locking to prevent concurrency problems

Tags: mysql, select, concurrency

So I'm working in an environment with high concurrency. What I want to do is select a row from the mysql database based on a certain property and then once I have that row, I want to set a "locked" flag in the row so I can do some work in php (which could take some time) and then unlock it when I'm done. What is the best way to do this in order to prevent concurrency problems that arise when having a separate SELECT and UPDATE command?

Answer (score 2):

using the select for update command :
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-locking-reads.html

Comment: Thanks! So would I just call:

'code'$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $database WHERE locked = 0 .. FOR UPDATE"); '/code'

and then mysql_fetch_assoc to fetch the row, get the ID from the row and then call the UPDATE command. Or can that be done in the same query?

Comment: the actual update would need to be a separate query. the table would need to be innodb and from the above man link:   Note

Locking of rows for update using SELECT FOR UPDATE only applies when autocommit is disabled (either by beginning transaction with START TRANSACTION or by setting autocommit to 0. If autocommit is enabled, the rows matching the specification are not locke

Comment: complement: Since MySQl 5.1, if you use BEGIN keyword to start a transaction the FOR UPDATE on select is now implicit. But anyway it's a good thing to use it. Of course use the UPDATE on the same MySQL session, so on the same php/http query.